# How to make only one cell editable in smart table sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using a sapui5 smart table to list down my products. It includes product code, product description and order quantity.

Among these three fields i want to update only the order quantity. It should be an inline editing in the table.

In my smart table i have enabled the property "editable" as "true". It makes the entire row is editable. Instead of making entire row editable, i want make only one cell to be editable.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRa6T.png)

```
 <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entityType="ZDEMO_C_MyEntityType" persistencyKey="SmartFilter_Explored">
 </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>

 <smartTable:SmartTable id="mySmartTable" 
      smartFilterId="smartFilterBar"
      tableType="GridTable" 
      editable="true" 
      entitySet="ZDEMO_C_MyEntity" 
      useVariantManagement="false" 
      useTablePersonalisation="true" 
      header="My Products" 
      showRowCount="true" 
      useExportToExcel="true" 
      enableAutoBinding="true">
 </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a sap ui table inside the smart table and add columns with customdata property. Follow these steps.

1. Make editable="true" as editable="false"
2. In your xml, make sure to add this namespace  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
3. Within the smarttable tag add below.

   ```
   <smartTable:SmartTable .................................

            <Table>
               <columns>
                   <Column>
                       <customData>
                           <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "OrderQty", "leadingProperty": "OrderQty", "columnIndex":"2"}'/>
                       </customData>
                       <Text text="Order Qty"/>
                   </Column>

               </columns>
               <items>
                   <ColumnListItem>
                       <cells>
                           <Input value="{OrderQty}" type="Number" editable="true"/>
                       </cells>
                   </ColumnListItem>
               </items>
           </Table>

     </smartTable:SmartTable>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 ways:

1. Make use of "**field controls**" concept. It requires adding a special properties within your *entity type*, which define the state of the fields (cells). Also some *annotations* have to be introduced (in the metadata.xml by backend) to initiate the handling.

   Here is a link where concept described using **Form** control as an example, but the same rules are applicable for **Table** as well:
   https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/06/dynamic-field-control-using-annotations-in-sapui5/
2. Redefine the *table rows manually* in your XML and bind the needed cell(s) against the property of the *local JSON model*, which could be changed depending on some conditions (e.g. Edit button press).

The 1st approach is better from the architectural perspective but requires some data model modifications (from the backend side).

The 2nd approach allows to do everything on UI and program some complex UI logic, which defines the cells state.

You choose.

Answer (score 0):

### Add below tag inside table to make your column editable

```
<table:Column sortProperty="Max_Capacity" filterProperty="Max_Capacity"  id="maxCapCol">
    <Label text="Max Capacity"/>
    <table:template>
        <Input text="{Max_Capacity}" />
    </table:template>
</table:Column>
```